# VBA Excel-2010 How do you add data to an external workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking into how best to insert data into an external workbook. I tried using AOD but I was wondering if there was a quick and easy way to just read and wright cells.

Something like
Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1").Value = "Hello World"

But to be able to do that on the external excel workbook file.

Comment: Put the other workbook in a variable and reference it. Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)      Dim wbOther As Workbook Set wbOther = ThisWorkbook

Comment: `Worksheets` is implicitly saying `Application.Worksheets`, which is a roundabout way of saying `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`: if you want to access the `Worksheets` collection of another workbook, you need to qualify the member call with a `Workbook` object instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variables to hold you workbooks and reference those

```
Dim wb As Workbook , path As String, wbOther As Workbook 
path = "workbookpath"
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(path) 
Set wbOther = ThisWorkbook 

wbOther.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Comment: I got a subscript out of range usiing Private Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook, path As String, wbOther As Workbook
    path = "pathToFile"
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)
    Set wbOther = ThisWorkbook
    wbOther.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "test"
End Sub

Comment: You need to write the full path for  pathToFile and you need a sheet called sheet1.

Comment: Okay it works, but I want to give this file to say 5 people and have them enter the data. Then I want to wright that data to an excel file. Is there any way i can use a connection and avoid actually opening the workbook?

Comment: you have to open the workbook in order to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
Workbooks("BookName").Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1").Value = "Hello World"
```